# Python code function not updating variables properly

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm attempting to make first a simple text based room based game where you can go from room to room and it gives you a description and you can walk around. after 1 input the output works accordingly. After it asks you to input again and you input a direction the program does nothing.
I have defined each of the different room1, room2 etc earlier in the code. I think it's to do with my direction function and the x y variables but I'm not entirely sure where the problem lies

```
import time
import sys
x=1
y=1
def direction():
    global x
    global y

    prompt = input("\nChoose a direction using AWSD:\n")
    if prompt == "a" or prompt == "A":
        x -= 1
    elif prompt == "s" or prompt == "S":
        y -= 1
    elif prompt == "w" or prompt == "W":
        y += 1
    elif prompt == "d" or prompt == "D":
        x += 1

def stutter(text):
    for c in text:
        print(c, end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(.04)
stutter(""""You wake up in a dark room with a rusty iron door. There is a small
circular window casting a dim light across the room. Theres two doors leading
out. One forward and one to the right.""")
direction()






if x==1 and y==1:
    stutter(room1)
    direction()
elif x==1 and y==2:
    stutter(room2)
    direction()
elif x==1 and y==3:
    stutter(room3)
    direction()
elif x==2 and y==1:
    stutter(room4)
    direction()
elif x==2 and y==2:
    stutter(room5)
    direction()
elif x==2 and y==2:
    stutter(room6)
    direction()
elif x==3 and y==1:
    stutter(room7)
    direction()
elif x==3 and y==2:
    stutter(room8)
    direction()
elif x==3 and y==3:
    stutter(room9)
    direction()
else:
    stutter("You hit a wall")
    direction()
```

Comment: The whole `if-elif` part must be enclosed in an infinite loop, `direction()` calls must be removed except the first one (also included in the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You have to introduce a `while` loop like this:

```
while(True):
    if x==1 and y==1:
        stutter(room1)
    elif x==1 and y==2:
        stutter(room2)
    elif x==1 and y==3:
        stutter(room3)
    elif x==2 and y==1:
        stutter(room4)
    elif x==2 and y==2:
        stutter(room5)
    elif x==2 and y==2:
        stutter(room6)
    elif x==3 and y==1:
        stutter(room7)
    elif x==3 and y==2:
        stutter(room8)
    elif x==3 and y==3:
        stutter(room9)
    else:
        stutter("You hit a wall")
    direction()
```

Otherwise it only asks once, because `stutter()` is not called again.

On a sidenote you should try to understand arrays and maybe dicts, because they could get rid of that long list of coordinate checking.